# How to place the cursor in middle of textbox netbeans java

Tags: java, netbeans, properties

I have a TextField that I'm forcing to load cursor in middle of it .Is there a way to do cursor positioning in the Netbeans 7.2?

Answer (score 0):

JTextFiend.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

Assuming your using the GUI Builder in netbeans, click on the JTextField item and under properties you'll see "HorizontalAlignment" with a drop-down list in which you can select "CENTER".

The caret can be positioned at the front (LEADING), center (CENTER) or the end (TRAILING). If you want it in some other strange place you might want to create your own listeners which moves the caret based on user input.